# "UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter" but the layout is not nil

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to set a UICollectionViewController, but I always get 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter' although I did initialized the layout and set it in the viewDidLoad.

This is what I have (Just created this VC):

```
class NotificationVC: UICollectionViewController{

let cellId = "notificationCell"
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavBar()
    navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("notification.vc.title", comment: "Notification")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.appWhite

    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical


    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
}
```

Comment: Not strictly related but an issue none the less.  You are registering a cell with the collection view, setting the delegate and the datasource and then completely replacing the collection view thus rendering what you have just done pointless.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thanks, I deleted this line as it was not working anyway. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance for `NotificationVC` from another view controller you should initialized the class with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object.

If you are pushing `NotificationVC` from another view controller, change it like this

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
let notificationVC = NotificationVC(collectionViewLayout: layout)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(notificationVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I really can't see what I'm doing wrong with this.

Comment: @JohnDoah what is the previous view controller of NotificationVC. How do you open NotificationVC?

Comment: I access it from a tabbar.

Comment: @JohnDoah Show the code how do you associate the NotificationVC with the tabbar

Comment: I will as soon as I can, may take me a couple of days as I stuck with no internet on my computer now.